# How can I confiuger a windows service from the command line

Tags: windows, service, batch-file, windows-service, batch

I have a windows service that I've written. I'd like to make it easy for my server team to install it. So I'm building a little batch script.

One of the things that I require is for it to be setup with "Log on as:" set to "Local System account"

By default when I install it with `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe myService.exe` it comes up with the "This Account" option.

Is there a way I can configure that option from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
sc.exe config myServiceName obj= "LocalSystem"
```

with `sc` you can change all kinds of configuration settings for a service.

Note the weird syntax with a space after the equal sign.